# How do I create a drop down in a Rails form where the user can change the default value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'd like to have a drop down in my Rails form where users can select an area of a city, e.g. "Marchmont", "New Town", "Baberton" etc, when adding an order. I'd like that once they have made a selection, this will then be the default selection for the following times they use the form to add an order (so that they don't have to keep selecting it) but also that they can change their selection at any time. Hope that makes sense. I'm using the Simple Form gem. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You could add a field `default_city_area` to the `User` model, then store the selected value in that field and use it as the default value for your form next time.

Answer (score 0):

@Steve

I will make a couple of assumptions.

1.) you know how to create forms within the rails templating engine. 
2.) you understand how to create a dropdown menu using the Simple Form gem

So you have a couple of options based on what you actually want to accomplish. Based on what you are briefly describing, it sounds like you have some kind of an e-commerce/checkout situation that you want auto-completion to make it easier for a user.

there are a couple of approaches to storing this data.

Saving the user Data.

1.) Save it right on the user model under district_of_last_order

2.) Save it right on the order model that a user `has_many` orders. Then you can pull the first order's city district and select that

Personally I would lean on #2 as you probably want to be able to tightly couple the order with the user and saving that information twice is redundant since you can always do something like `current_user.orders.first.district` or whatever,

in your ERB where you build the form you can then do something along these lines:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>

... other input fields 

<% if current_user.orders.first %>
  <%= f.input as: :select selected: current_user.orders.first.district %>
<% else %>
  <%= ... your regular dropdown menu here without the default  %>
<% end %>


... rest of your form
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of using gems, I have had good results with select2-rails.